# Mathematical inconsistencies with await Delay ()

Tags: javascript, while-loop, async-await, timer, delay

I'm having some trouble with setting a timer.
If this takes approximately 5 seconds:

```js
Delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

showCoins = 0

setTick(() => {
  if (IsControlJustPressed(2, 48)) {
    showCoins = 5
    setTimer()
  }
});

async function setTimer() {
  while (showCoins != 0) {
    await Delay(1000)
    --showCoins
    print(showCoins)
  }
}
```

Why does this take 01:24 minutes, instead of also 5 seconds?:

```js
Delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

showCoins = 0

setTick(() => {
  if (IsControlJustPressed(2, 48)) {
    showCoins = 5000
    setTimer()
  }
});

async function setTimer() {
  while (showCoins != 0) {
    await Delay(1)
    --showCoins
    print(showCoins)
  }
}
```

I need the second one because I need something for 4.3 seconds.

And I can't use setTimeout and bools, because if I used it and pressed the key twice it would set to false before the five seconds of the second press had passed.

Comment: Try something like 100ms x 43 "coins", 1ms is a fairly short time for a javascript timer (and printing 5k times takes some time too) so you may see a lot of overhead.

Comment: There are [minimum timeouts in some circumstances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays). And in general, you cannot rely on a timeout of `x` to be *exactly* `x`. If some task takes a bit more time, the later scheduled ones will have to wait for it to finish.